# How fast do the MacLaurin coefficients of $\tanh(z)$ converge for $z = 1$? Does distance to nearest pole determine convergence rate?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, taylor-expansion

In the Oct 12 issues of [SIAM News](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/trefethen/oct12.pdf) it states that for a mathematician not to know that the coefficients of the Taylor series for  $\tanh(z)$ centered at $z=1$ decay as $(2/\pi)^n$ is like a physicist not to be able to work out when a stone dropped from a height of 10m hits the ground. I am ashamed to admit I am not familiar with this computation. I worked out a few terms of the Taylor series, but they're fairly messy, not obviously geometric. The article makes it sound like it's based on proximity to the pole at $z=i\pi/2$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) makes no mention of this. Is there some relationship between the rate of convergence of a Taylor series and the proximity of the center to a pole?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article does not speak of the Taylor series centered on $z=1$. It speaks of the Taylor (MacLaurin) series centered on $z=0$, evaluated at $z=1$.

The sketch would be:

1. $\tanh(z)$ has poles at the zeros of $\cosh(z)$, which are $z= \pi k i + \frac{\pi i}{2}$.
2. Hence the nearest poles to the origin are $\pm \frac{\pi i}{2}$
3. Hence the MacLaurin series $$ a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + \cdots$$ converges on a circle that extends up to that point(s) (radius$= \pi/2>1)$.
4. Hence the MacLaurin series at $z=1$ (which concides with the series of the Maclaurin coefficients $ a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \cdots $) converges.
5. Then, by [Cauchy-Hadamard theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem) $|a_n| \to R^{-n} = (2 /\pi)^n$
   (in the article: "so So the Maclaurin coefficients decay at the rate $(2 /\pi)^n$")
6. Then the series  $ a_0 + a_1 + a_2 + \cdots $ converges as a geometric series, at a rate $(2 /\pi)^n$.

Comment: This is just brilliant ! +1